# total newbie please help with installing the ISO

Tags: system-installation

I have been a Windows user all my life but want to move to Linux.  I have downloaded the ISO file for Ubuntu Late..now what?  please help  thanks alot   Craig

Comment: Now write that .iso file to a USB drive with a program such as [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). When that is done, boot from that drive, and have fun.

Comment: What is "Ubuntu Late"? Setup your computer as a dual-boot machine, so you can boot into either OS. This way you can still run Windows-only apps, or do BIOS/firmware updates.

Comment: Write it to a usb drive using [etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). It is (almost) impossible to do something wrong using etcher. WARNING: all data on your usb-drive will be lost. back it up first

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Answer (score 1):

You should first use a hypervisor like VirtualBox (free) on your Windows, to create a virtual Linux, and experiment there, while you still use Windows.. once you are ready to convert your hardware, and know what you are doing, then install on the hardware.. this way you will be able to revert back to saved snapshots, with ease, when you screw up..

Comment: There is no harm in booting the startup media in "Try Ubuntu" mode.

Comment: He wants to `move` and he seems not to be ready.. correct?